# Assign background image from attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set different background-image to several divs. I am setting an attr that contains the path to the background image that specific div needs to use. The problem comes when I try to pull the attr into the function that sets the bg.

This isn't working but you can see what I am doing.

```
$('.someDiv').each(function(){
    thisDataBgPath = $(this).attr('data-bg');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../images/' + thisDataBgPath + ')');
});
```

I tried background, and backgroundImage as well and neither work.

When I use a normal image path it works, but when I try to inject a variable it doesn't work.

the html is very basic

```
       <div id="item">
            <div class="" data-bg="section-bg-large-career-1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="" data-bg="section-bg-large-career-2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="" data-bg="section-bg-large-career-3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to post some of the HTML as well

Comment: You sure the path is correct?

Comment: On a side note - instead of `.attr('data-bg')` use `.data('bg')`

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-bg');` should be `$(this).data('bg');` See [jQuery `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: `var thisDataBgPath` instead `thisDataBgPath` ... maybe?

Comment: any errors in your console? you'll need to post some more information.

Comment: You can use the console for this kind of debugging. Just insert a `console.log(thisDataBgPath)` after the line where you instantiate that variable and see the result in the console.

Comment: Yea i logged in in console and path is right. I was under the impression that .attr was faster than .data but if thats the problem that would be a quick fix

Comment: there is no elements with a class name `someDiv`

Comment: Half an hour later you finally decide to post the markup.

Comment: sorry I wasn't fast enough haha, I rather figure things out then sit here and hope someone tells me what I'm doing wrong... But anyway, just changing it to .data('bg') worked... weird since i was able to pull the info with .attr also.

Comment: `data('bg')` and `attr('data-bg')` makes no difference when getting a data attribute from the markup, so that is strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. You might have an incorrect path? Here's a quick test with your code. I just removed the ../images part since I'm not testing a local image.

http://jsfiddle.net/DvNjA/

```
$('.someDiv').each(function(){
    thisDataBgPath = $(this).attr('data-bg');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + thisDataBgPath + ')');
});
```

Comment: Yea It should work, somehow it only works using .data there must be some weird garbage going on in the code on this site... This is why I hate picking up other peoples half done projects haha